# Curve of intersection of the cone is $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and the ellipsoid is $3x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2y$. Find parameterization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametrization

Curve of intersection of the cone is $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and the ellipsoid is $3x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2y$. Find parameterization

Solution:

$z^2 = x^2 + y^2$

$3x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2y \implies 4x^2 + 2y^2 - 2y = 0$

$\implies 8x^2 + (2y-1)^2 = 1$ (How?)

So, C lies in the elliptical cylinder given by this equation In XY plane eclipse can be parameterized by

I don't get below:

$x = cos(t)\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}$

$y = \frac{1}{2}(sin(t)+1)$

$z = [x^2(t) + y^2(t)] = \sqrt{0.5sin(t) - 1/8cos^2(t) + 1/2}$

---

I don't understand how they get from $4x^2 + 2y^2 - 2y = 0$ to  $8x^2 + (2y-1)^2 = 1$

The eliptic cylinder formula is

$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$

now sure how to use that to parameterize this: $8x^2 + (2y-1)^2 = 1$

any help appreciated

Comment: Your first "how" is answered by completing the square. The second is that the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ is parametrized by $x = a \cos(t)$, $y = b \sin(t)$, similar to the parametrization of a circle. Letting $v = 2y-1$, then the elliptical cylinder has equation $\frac{x^2}{1/8} + v^2 = 1$. You can apply the parametrization, and then solve for $y$.

Comment: they got $y = 1/2(sin(t)+1)$ whereas that gives me 1(sin(t)) ?

Comment: Using the parametrization formula, I get $2y - 1 = v = \sin(t)$. Now you can solve for $y$.